# django-cms not using user's language for its core translations

Tags: python, django, translation, django-cms, administration

*Edit: found out this happens on a very basic project generated by **djangocms-installer**, I've reported [an issue about this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3798).*

I've setup a simple project with [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) and my client's native language is `french`. Thanks to [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/django-cms/), French translation is always up to date. Not quite sure why, everything related to django-cms app is not being translated (strings in administration, admin toolbar, etc).

Strings like "Double click to edit", "Create Page", etc. are still in english even when Currently logged in user has its settings set to french `(Accueil › Cms › User settings › gableroux)`.

[image: django-cms admin not being translated]
[image: django-cms admin not being translated, disabeld django-admin-style]

Note that all other strings in administration are translated to french

> Administration de Django
>   Bienvenue, gableroux. Modifier le mot de passe / Déconnexion
>   Administration du site

etc.

### Generated settings

*Note here that I'm not using those settings on production, this is a sample project I generated for this particular issue, `SECRET_KEY` is not being used anywhere ;)

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
"""
Django settings for omg project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@j#r%*#u&2v!yxih1n11e)4gg%k+)1bm&=mdhdcpzn9#ptn597'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition





ROOT_URLCONF = 'omg.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'omg.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omg', 'static'),
)
SITE_ID = 1

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware'
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.cms_settings'
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omg', 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'mptt',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_flash',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'south',
    'reversion',
    'omg'
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('fr', gettext('fr')),
    ('en', gettext('en')),
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    'default': {
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
    },
    1: [
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'fr',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('fr'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'en',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
    ],
}

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('fullwidth.html', 'Fullwidth'),
    ('sidebar_left.html', 'Sidebar Left'),
    ('sidebar_right.html', 'Sidebar Right')
)

CMS_PERMISSION = True

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}

DATABASES = {
    'default':
        {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': 'project.db', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'PORT': ''}
}
```

If you have any idea or you feel like I may provide more informations, please let me know.

### pip freeze

```
Django==1.6.10
Pillow==2.7.0
South==1.0.2
argparse==1.3.0
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-classy-tags==0.5.2
django-cms==3.0.9
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.8.1
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.5
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.1
djangocms-googlemap==0.2
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.1
djangocms-link==1.5
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.4.3
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.999
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.5.1
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this issue has been resolved already on the django-cms project Github: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3798

The final answer (once the patch was applied that removed the locale `fr_FR`) was to restart the server -- only with the server being restarted is the locale taken into consideration.